# How can I create a "Health Check" for an Azure Storage Queue

Tags: azure-storage

So when developing an app utilizing Azure Storage Queues and a Web Job, I feel like I need some sort of health check (via API) to ensure my Azure Storage Queue is properly configured for each environment up to prod. **I don't have access (directly) to view the Dashboard or Kudu.**

My thought thus far was to just create an API route that returns a bool that tells me if I was able to create the queue if it doesn't exist, and peek at a message (even if one doesn't exist), like :

```
    public async Task<bool> StorageQueueHealthCheck()
    {
        return await _queueManager.HealthCheck();
    }
```

And the implementation:

```
public async Task<bool> HealthCheck()
{
   try
  {
      CloudQueue queue = _queueClient.GetQueueReference(QueueNames.reportingQueue);
      queue.CreateIfNotExists();

      CloudQueueMessage peek = await queue.PeekMessageAsync();

      return true; // as long as we were able to peek at messages
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Is this a bad approach? Is there another way to "health check" certain Azure functionality when the dashboard is abstracted away? If I absolutely needed I would be able to view the Kudu but would rather just use an API and hit it via Swagger.

Comment: I wanted to understand if you want something to be on a triggered basis. There can be another approach also.

Comment: I think for my needs, this is going to work fine, but I think for the sake of completeness maybe expand your answer and say how it could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good. You can also try [CloudQueue.FetchAttributeAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.fetchattributesasync.aspx) since the payload would be smaller when the message size is large.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it's weird there's no native "ping" method or something to check the status? I often wonder if sometimes the Azure team needs to pretend like there is no dashboard/web interface sometimes, haha.

Comment: Actually "ping" method is not needed under most scenarios. We should always assume the queue exists in the system since the permission of creating/deleting queue should only be granted to super admins just like creating/deleting data base. Is there a "ping" method for data base? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good approach, please just make sure you do have a retry mechanism so that your healthcheck does not just return false for intermittent failures.

Second Approach,
Instead of api which will perform the job only is trigger there should be a console app (webjob) which does this task on regular interval (1min) and based on some logic lets say all 'creates' in last 10mins threw error sends an email. This can be used in all environments.

Comment: Yeah, I did think about that and added it immediately after asking this question, haha, but thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Well as long as the Storage Queue is created and it exists, it shouldn't need to be pinged like that, should it?

Comment: The Azure storage libraries have built-in retry mechanisms (though it's a good idea to know how to customize them).